# Search Button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this question has been asked many of times about how to create a search button.  I am very new to C# programming and I am having a hard time creating a search and just haven't found what I am looking for from other posts.  So I hope someone can help me.

I have created a Windows Form Application and I have a form setup using "Details" view from my DataSet and the data shows up correctly in the application when I scroll from record to record.  My data is stored in a sdf file.  I want to have people either enter in an "account number" or a persons "last name" and then be able to hit the search button.  And after the search button the prearranged fields would update with the information.  For the ability to either choose the "last name" or the "account number"  I can have the items listed in a combo box if need be.

I have included a copy of the code some of the naming of the items have been changed as to not disclose my profession.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.ComponentModel;   
using System.Data;   
using System.Drawing;   
using System.Linq;   
using System.Text;   
using System.Windows.Forms;   

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1   
{
public partial class Form1 : Form   
{   
    public Form1()   
    {   
        InitializeComponent();   
    }   

    private void custtableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   
        this.Validate();   
        this.custtableBindingSource.EndEdit();    
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.custDataSet);   

    }    

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   

    }   

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)   
    {   

    }   

    private void custtableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   
        this.Validate();   
        this.custtableBindingSource.EndEdit();   
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.custDataSet);   

    }   

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'custDataSet.custtable' table.    You can move, or remove it, as needed.   
        this.custtableTableAdapter.Fill(this.custDataSet.custtable);   

    }   

    private void file_Name_12TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   

    }   

    private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {   
        try   
        {   
            this.custtableTableAdapter.FillBy(this.custDataSet.custtable);    
        }   
        catch (System.Exception ex)   
        {   
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
        }   

    }   

    private void btnfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the custtableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click and custtableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1 ? Thet are the same, if they are two buttons doing the same thing then you can use the same method from both buttons (though why two buttons to do the same thing I do not know).

Anyway, you have some choices and it depends on the datasize, speed needed, whether the data should be offline or db locked and so on...

1. Set you queries/stored procedures (sprocs are safer) to allow for limiting the result. This lets the DB do all the hard work - it is what DB's are designed for.
2. Read everything into memory (your table fill) and select off the table - not to disimilar really with Linq queries. This means all the data is offline and you will need to decide when and how you write it back to the database (if at all).

PS: I am intrigued, what is your profession that your pseudonym here is not enough to hide behind? Imagination gone wild !

Comment: Currently there are about 15k records between two tables, the search will focus on one of the two tables.  the information will be stored o a network drive and multiple users will be accessing the data.  I work for a major cable provider

Comment: OK, you said you are using SDF file. I am not well up on the capabilities of SQL Server CE, but I would suggest you will be using option 1 from above. You will need to decide if you want to lock records between reading them and writing them back or allowing uncommitted reads etc as you say you will have multiple users. Your question is related to the search rather than SQL/SPROCs, so I would generally say that you need SPOCS that you can call with input from your form and returns the data. The SPROC will just use Where clauses.

Comment: Wolf would you be able to provide a copy of what the code looks like, I am baby so to say when it comes to programming so I am not to familiar with how it should be written out.